# Kamailio 3.1 problems, calls between subscriber fails among other things

Tags: sip, openser

I've installed Kamailio on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS via: 
http://www.kamailio.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/packages:debs

Updated /etc/kamailio/kamctlrc with: 
SIP_DOMAIN=MY-IP 
DBENGINE=MYSQL

I've also installed the kamailio-mysql-modules via apt-get.

Then I've run kamdbctl create and created the MySQL database.

After that I've started Kamailio via kamctl start. Success.

At last I've added two users: 
kamctl add 100 PASS1 
kamctl add 101 PASS2

Now I should be able to call between the SIP clients with the subscribers, correct?

But when I try nothing happens. I also found out that no matter what I use for username and password on the clients, they WILL register successfully.

What is wrong?

Comment: Update on the problem. 

When I register to 2 clients I can see from the kamctl ul show that they both appear. 
But one client is registered with it's local IP, the other one with a public IP. 

I am able to call from the one with the local IP to the one with the public IP. But not the other way around, which make sense since the local IP can't be found. 

So my question is: 
- Why are both client not registered with a public IP? 
- Why can I still register other devices without password etc. I will only allow registrered devices to register.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the default configuration for Kamailio, which is very open and insecure. In order to get some NAT support there's a flag in the kamailio.cfg file to turn on NAt support, which means that Kamailio will store the sender's IP address in the registration, not the address in the SIP message.

Good luck. If you have any further questions, I recommend the Kamailio user mailing list, which you can find on http://www.kamailio.org

/O